# Fetching data added in the previous hour only

Tags: php, mysql

How to get the records that were added from the beginning of the previous hour until the end of the previous hour. The below brings the data added in the last hour only, which is not what I want :

```
WHERE last_login >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 hour);
```

Comment: use between sub1 and sub 2 hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why the negative rating ??!
Anyway, the following is the syntax I was looking for

```
last_login BETWEEN 
DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') 
AND 
DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR), '%Y-%m-%d %H:59:59')
```